# Netlify environment variables that were set in the UI are injected as undefined when running a local dev server

Tags: environment-variables, netlify, netlify-cli

I have set some environment variables in the Netlify UI.

See here:

[image]

I am trying to use them in my code like this:

```
    console.log("AUTH0_DOMAIN:");
    console.log(process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN);
    console.log("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID:");
    console.log(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID);
    console.log("AUTH0_AUDIENCE:");
    console.log(process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE);
```

When starting up the CLI local dev server using `ntl dev` it looks like the environment variables are injected:

[image]

But they all come through as `undefined` as shown here in the console:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Why are they coming through as undefined?

P.S. I know I should not be using secret keys here because they will be exposed, but I still want to know how to do it for non-secret stuff.

UPDATE: The environment variables are also undefined after deploying live to Netlify. So it's broken on the live version and dev version.

UPDATE 2: Assigning it to a variable, as per below, also doesn't work:

```
const a_d = process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN;
console.log(a_d); // This prints undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am building a Vue app.

Turns out all [Vue env variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code) need to be prefixed with `VUE_APP_` inside the code and the Netlify UI.

So for example, it becomes `const authDomain = process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;` in the code and you also have to use `VUE_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN` in the Netlify UI.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
netlify link
```

The `netlify link` command will link your local project to Netlify. [See docs](https://docs.netlify.com/cli/get-started/#link-and-unlink-sites).

I did not think it was necessary to use `netlify link` because I already installed the Netlify CLI and was deploying my site automatically with GitHub but apparently it's needed.